# How can I use conditional formatting to update cells based off of a seating chart list?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have three columns of data. 
Column N contains desk numbers 
Column O current desk occupant
Column P future desk occupant

To the left of these columns I have a bunch of cells with each desk number assigned to each cell line.

I would love to know a way that if there's no name in Column O to turn the desk number or individual cell to the left of Columns N-P green.

And if there's a name present to turn the cell red. Meaning the desk is occupied.

Answer (score 0):

Clear any existing CF from ColumnM, select it, fill it with green colour (standard fill) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=LEN(O1)=1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly.. Ive tried your solution but the cells I need to turn red and green are not in the columns that have the names and desk numbers. They're the cells to the left of those columns which each have a desk number as well.

Comment: I thought I did that...... I have three columns and to the left of those columns are cells with desk numbers.